# Convert Pandas Column which Consist of list of JSON into new columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have DataFrame which have 3 columns:

```
order_id  user_id  Details
5c7c9     A        [{"amount": "160",'id':'p2'},{"amount": "260",'id':'p3'}]
5c5c4     B        [{"amount": "10",'id':'p1'},{"amount": "260",'id':'p3'}]
```

I want my final Dataframe to be like:

```
order_id  user_id  amount  id
5c7c9     A        160     p2
5c7c9     A        260     p3
5c5c4     B        10      p1
5c5c4     B        260     p3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well my first requirement was to deal reading products column only for that i use                                                                                                                 
 from bson.json_util import dumps
import json
r = collection.find()
test=dumps(r)

json_test=json.loads(test)

df = pd.concat(map(lambda x: DataFrame(x[1]['products']), enumerate(json_test)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if necessary convert values to list of dictianaries by `ast.literal_eval`, then use dictionary comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add to original:

```
import ast

#df['Details'] = df['Details'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df1 = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in df.pop('Details').items()})
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

df = df.join(df1, rsuffix='_').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  order_id user_id amount  id
0    5c7c9       A    160  p2
1    5c7c9       A    260  p3
2    5c5c4       B     10  p1
3    5c5c4       B    260  p3
```

Comment: Getting Error:   ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'amount': '285', '_id': '5bf69f5ca59f6202a7c95434', 'dmrp': '95', 'quantity': '3', 'mrp': '115'}, {'amount': '140', '_id': '5beaba4d1e748515b8558988', 'dmrp': '70', 'quantity': '2', 'mrp': '80'}, {'amount': '21.17', '_id': '5c0f4f194449714eddac9554', 'dmrp': '21.17', 'quantity': '1', 'mrp': '25'}]

Comment: @souravkhanna - Be free omit it, it is necessary only if strings in column `Details`.

Comment: Other Error came: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['_id'], dtype='object')

Comment: @souravkhanna - Edited answer, change `df = df.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)` to `df = df.join(df1, rsuffix='_').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: It works . it was my fault i didnt mentioned '_id' in question :(

Comment: How can i extract only amount column?

Comment: @jezrael how would you adapt this solution if some of the rows in the original df were blank for the Details column?  When I try this solution with some blank rows, I get a blank df as a result.  Only seems to work with all the rows have json in the Details column

Comment: @Snapula - You can try change `df.pop('Details').items()` to `df.pop('Details').dropna().items()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s=pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in zip(df1.index,df1.Details) for z in y])
s=s.merge(df1,left_on=0,right_index=True).drop(['Details',0],1)
print(s.pop(1).apply(pd.Series).join(s))

  amount  id order_id user_id
0    160  p2    5c7c9       A
1    260  p3    5c7c9       A
2     10  p1    5c5c4       B
3    260  p3    5c5c4       B
```

Comment: How can i extract only amount column?

Comment: @souravkhanna the final df which you have do `df['amount']`